# Show element with number value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to Show element with number value, with click function

**html**

```
<p>
    <button>Run</button>
</p>

<p>
   <span id="demo">1000</span>
</p>

<p id="result">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

**jquery**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#demo').filter(function(index){
    var num = parseInt(this.textContent);
    return num >= 1000;
    }).find('#result').show();
});
```

**Css**

```
#result{
    display:none;
}
```

**[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ve4eaa9y/)**

Comment: **id** should unique in HTML document therefore the is no need of filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. Basically on button click you are getting the number(innerHTML) and if that number is >= 1000 then call show() on result or call hide() on result.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var number = $('#demo').html();
  if (number >= 1000) {
    $("#result").show();
  }else{
    $("#result").hide();
  }
});
```

[Here is the link to updated JSFriddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqLqoskw/)

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not really using filter in an appropriate context. Filter returns an array while all you really need is just the value from the element and to check it.
2. You're also using `find` wrongly as find only looks for descendants, which result is not

You can simply your code to this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var num = parseInt($("#demo").html());
  if (num >= 1000) $("#result").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse text content of the demo div and show result div if value is greater than or equal to 1000.

Example Snippet:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if (parseInt($('#demo').html()) >= 1000) {
    $('#result').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#result {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button>Run</button>
</p>

<p>
  <span id="demo">1000</span>
</p>

<p id="result">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```